Installing GRUB on New Linux OS
I am trying to create a new bootable installation of a custom-created Linux (made with Yocto) on a new partition of sda.  The files are already on the partition /dev/sda1.  Also, I've booted into the LMDE (Linux Mint Debian Edition) 6 live ISO, and I'm trying to use the version of Grub included with LMDE.  If I type:
$ sudo grub-install /dev/sda
I get:
Installing for i386-pc platform
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `overlay'.

I've also tried mounting the partition /dev/sda1 and using chroot, but then I cannot use the grub commands because grub is not installed on the target file system.

I posit /dev/sda is the install media and you need to try using sdb or something else.   (USB Pen drives are often designated as /dev/sdX - and if it was used to boot the system its probable its /dev/sda).   Also "overlay" seems to imply some kind of hybrid disk - like you might have on a Bootable USB. Try using blkid to identify the devices.

In my case, the install media is an optical drive /dev/sr0.  There are no USB drives, so the sole SATA SSD is /dev/sda.
